# asymptotic distribution of outlier detection tests

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, asymptotics

What is the asymptotic distribution of Dixon and Grubbs discordancy test statistics, if the data are from a normal distribution (such as simulated data, perhaps).

Comment: Asymptotic distribution of what?  The test statistics?  Their p-values?

Comment: thanx Whuber... and want to know the asymptotic distribution of these test statistics